# Pronunciation of "theodicy"

Tags: pronunciation

I am confused: Please listen to the audio file from google [here](http://www.google.com/dictionary?source=dict-chrome-ex&sl=en&tl=en&q=theodicy)

**This can't be right, can it?**

Comment: Hey Buddy, I'm an ESL student, too. And, when I want to know the pronunciation of some word I prefer to look [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/theodicy). It might help you better than Google translator pronunciation!

Comment: Don't sweat your confusion - 99% of the English speakers you run into (outside of a seminary, perhaps) will never have heard of this word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's funnny; the Google audio switched the consonant sounds. He actually says thee-AH-si-dee. The correct pronunciation is pretty close to "the Odyssey" but with a harder 'th' than you would normally use for "the."

Answer (score 6):

The correct pronunciation is `θēˈädəsē` which sounds like "thee-ahd-ih-see". The audio file appears to have mixed up the `d` and `s` sounds and is incorrect. Alternative pronunciations do exist but none of them would swap the `d` and `s`.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, and the sound file from [Howjsay](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=%20theodicy&submit=Submit) agrees.